# Word 2016 with the "Word could not create the work file" error message - What has been done, and not sure what to do next

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, 32-bit, preview

My wife is having a problem with the "Word could not create the work file" error message, which has to be clicked on like 20 to 30 times to clear all the pop up windows.  I tried the Microsoft solution searching for HKCR\CLSID{84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE} in the Windows Registry but it doesn't show up.  However just by the value between the {} it comes up about two dozen times throughout the registry.  So I am not sure what to delete.

It appears I got it to trigger somehow when, in File Explorer, I opened a document while it was in Preview Mode.

In our case we had the 64 bit preinstalled for Office 365 when we got the computer, but I have a license key for Office 2016 which is 32 bit so I uninstalled that and installed the 2016 version.  Seems like it fits the 64 bit to 32 bit pattern mentioned.  What I am trying to figure out is what else to try.  I've tried a couple of other solutions with temp variables with no success.

Comment: To search the registry for the previewer GUID string, can you this command-line (from a Command Prompt window) and post the output here? `reg query hkcr /f "84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE" /s`

Comment: Kindly check if this article was helpful :["Word could not create the work file" error message when you save a document in Microsoft Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/word-could-not-create-the-work-file)